# Show that un in a compact topological space, any infinite set has some limit point. When does the reverse hold?

Tags: general-topology

Show that un in a compact topological space,  any infinite set has some limit point. When does the reverse hold?

**My attemp:** I have done the proof but i dont know when the reverse hold. I have come up with some examples like $(0,1)$ with the usual topology. I think that in general a bounded metric space is a counterexample for the reverse.

How can I find the exact condiction so that the reverse holds?

Comment: In metric spaces the converse holds. More precisely, in $T_1$ spaces *limit point compactness* is equivalent to *countable compactness*, and in metric spaces this implies compactness.